# Show title for gridview for each row

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, export-to-excel

I am using this below code to set title for my gridview in my export to excel. Now I need to show this title for each row of the grid after export to excel.

Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

```
            if (gv.ID == "GridView1")
            {
                TableRow title = new TableRow();
                title.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
                TableCell titlecell = new TableCell();
                titlecell.ColumnSpan = 3;
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = "XYZ REPORT 2014";
                titlecell.Controls.Add(lbl);
                title.Cells.Add(titlecell);
                table.Rows.Add(title);
            }
            if (gv.ID == "GridView2")
            {
                TableRow title = new TableRow();
                title.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                TableCell titlecell = new TableCell();
                titlecell.ColumnSpan = 4;
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = "XYZ REPORT 2015";
                titlecell.Controls.Add(lbl);
                title.Cells.Add(titlecell);
                table.Rows.Add(title);
            }
```

Comment: where is this code written on the page.?

Comment: there is an event of Gridview called RowDataBound this Event is called for every rows that is bound to the gridview so if you want run some functionality for every row then use that Event.

Answer (score -1):

In alternate rows in your grid view use the heading

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
        {
            // Ur header row here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not coming for all rows. Also since I have columns already it also overrides the values and it shouldn't.